# Vue JS many of the same select drop downs using v-model

Tags: vue.js

How to have multiple select boxes in Vue

[image]

Imagine you had a v-for loop with a list of data that have an identical select box for each. 
How can these two select boxes share v-model to get their values without affecting each other, so they are separate?

```
new Vue({
 el: '...',
 data: {
 selected: ''
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is not clear enough, but may be you are looking for the following solution -

```js
new Vue({
  el : "#main",
  data:{
    tableData : [
      { 'name' : 'A', 'age' : 30 },
      { 'name' : 'C', 'age' : 50 },
      { 'name' : 'B', 'age' : 40 },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="main">
    <table border="4">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="row in tableData">
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.age }}</td>
        <td>
          <select v-model="row.name">
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```